# PowerPivot. Constract formula that first agregate data from one table and then use data from another table to compute result

Tags: pivot-table, powerpivot

I have two tables. One table contains two columns **RepresentativeID** and **SalesAmount**.

The second Table contains three columns **RepresentativeID**, **BaseAmount** and **RateCommision**.

A representative gets a commission of let say *1% all sales over 1000*.
I need to compute total commission for each representative.

How can I aggregate one table first and then connect it with another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, Iryna!

First, you need to connect your tables on RepresentativeID. 
For simplicty, I will call your first table "Sales", and the second table "Rep". 
Your data model then should look something like that:

[image]

Note that Rep table should be on 1 side, and Sales table on many side (1:*)

Then, in Sales table add measure:

```
Rep Sale = SUM(Sales[Amount])
```

and another measure:

```
Rep Commission = SUMX( Rep, ( [Rep Sale] - Rep[Base]) * Rep[Rate])
```

How it works:
to calculate commissions, you need to iterate by each representative. SUMX function iterates over table Rep, calculates sales for each of them, then calculates their commissions, and then sums them up.